# How to access the account information through URL after authenticating the oauth2.0 salesforce API?

Tags: php, api, salesforce

I am implementing salesforce.com api in my application. I got the authentication from auth2.0 and all other vital info. Now I want to get the account info from salesforce.com and display it on my application. I referred oauth2.0 identity url documentation, but unable to get the info. I am getting a 403 HTTP error code which says Access Denied or Forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a 403 from the identity service URL, then it sounds like you're not setting the authorization header correctly for that request, it should be

```
Authorization:OAuth {your access token}
```